# Django changes not reflecting AWS Nginx and got CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing while post a request

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nginx, gunicorn

I hosted my Django app on AWS with Nginx, gunicorn and Postgres. Now I got 3 issues

1. Django changes not reflecting
2. Style not working
3. CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing while post a request

**Style not working**

I added `STATIC_URL = '/static/' , STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` on **settings.py** and `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` on **urls.py**.

[image]

**CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing while post a request**

And I'm not using Django rest framework default authentication But I'm using just my own logic. *Here is it*

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST']) 
def student_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.data['name']
        password= request.data['password']
        try:
            user_obj = Admission.objects.get(name = name, password = password)
            return Response({"Token": user_obj.student_token}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Admission.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({"Error": "Invalid username or password!"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response({"Error": "Somthing went wrong!"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

[image]